# Filter SQL elements by field

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have these data in my database:

```
RELATION   VALUE
--------   -----
COD_1      VALUE1
COD_1      VALUE2
COD_1      VALUE3
COD_2      VALUE4
COD_2      VALUE5
COD_3      VALUE6
COD_3      VALUE7
```

I need getting which relation fits with a given value set. For example, if I have the following input values:

```
[0]
    VALUE1
    VALUE2
    VALUE3
```

The relation recovered must be COD_1, because all input values has COD_1 as their relation.

And if I have:

```
[0]
    VALUE1
    VALUE2
    VALUE3  
[1]
    VALUE6
    VALUE7
```

The values recovered must be COD_1 and COD_3.

Is there any way to do this with a SQL select query?

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT**: Input modification

Comment: 1) What is the result for the VALUE1,VALU2,VALUE6 ? Is it same COD1_1+COD_3 ?
2) can different CODs have the same value (is there intersection in values for CODs) ?

Comment: So you want the relations for which **all** values are present in the input?

Comment: 3) what version of oracle do you use ?

Comment: The result for VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE6 must be empty, because there is no relation which fit on them

Comment: Got it. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves your problem

```
select RELATION from 
(SELECT RELATION, LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RELATION) AS ip  from 
 input_table 
group by RELATION)A
where ip = 'VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I needed

Comment: Seems like this doesn't give correct result for VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE6,VALUE7

Comment: thank you for attention but i can't get how will tht won't work. i would love if you suggest any change.

Comment: It works in this way: where ip in ('VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3', 'VALUE6,VALUE7').

Comment: @Genzotto . . . This answers a different question but not the one you asked.  This does not return  COD_1 and COD_3 in the last scenario you mention.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you are right, I did not write the input well. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need all relations for which every value is present in the input, here is a query

```
WITH
    matching_values
    AS
        (SELECT *
         FROM mydata
         WHERE VALUE IN ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE6', 'VALUE7'))
SELECT DISTINCT a.relation
FROM (SELECT relation,
             COUNT (DISTINCT VALUE) AS n_vals
      FROM mydata
      GROUP BY relation) a,
     (SELECT relation,
             COUNT (DISTINCT VALUE) AS n_vals
      FROM matching_values
      GROUP BY relation) b
WHERE a.relation = b.relation
      AND a.n_vals = b.n_vals;
```

With the input having values 1,2,3,6,7 we get

```
+----------+
| RELATION |
+----------+
| COD_3    |
| COD_1    |
+----------+
```

With inputs having values 1,2,6,7 (Note: value 3 is missing so COD_1 is incomplete) we get

```
+----------+
| RELATION |
+----------+
| COD_3    |
+----------+
```

Here is the fiddle 
[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ed1f/6/0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've accepted @kiran gadhe solution because it's simpler for my development, but yours good too. Unfortunately I cannot accept more than one solution.

Comment: Glad to know that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select distinct RELATION from TABLE where values in ('VALUE_1', 'VALUE_2', 'VALUE_3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have at least 11gr2 version to use recursive subqueries. You can use it to get all different combinations of relations. Here is a short example how to generate those combinations:

```
with test_data as (
  select 'COD_1' relation from dual union all
  select 'COD_2' from dual union all
  select 'COD_3' from dual
),
recursive_subq(relation, codes) as (
  select relation,
         relation codes 
  from   test_data
  union all
  select t.relation,
         codes||','||t.relation 
  from   recursive_subq rs,
         test_data t
  where  rs.relation < t.relation
)
select codes
from   recursive_subq c
```

it returns

```
COD_1
COD_2
COD_3
COD_1,COD_2
COD_1,COD_3
COD_2,COD_3
COD_1,COD_2,COD_3
```

The main query concatenates the values for different relation combinations and compares it with the required (input data):

```
with initial_data as (
  select 'COD_1' relation, 'VALUE1' val from dual union all
  select 'COD_1', 'VALUE2' from dual union all
  select 'COD_1', 'VALUE3' from dual union all
  select 'COD_2', 'VALUE4' from dual union all
  select 'COD_2', 'VALUE5' from dual union all
  select 'COD_3', 'VALUE6' from dual union all
  select 'COD_3', 'VALUE7' from dual
),
input_data as (
  select 'VALUE1' val from dual union all
  select 'VALUE2' val from dual union all
  select 'VALUE3' val from dual union all
  select 'VALUE7' val from dual union all
  select 'VALUE6' val from dual
),
input_data_result as (
  select listagg(val,',') within group (order by val) input_values_listagg
  from   input_data
),
distinct_relations as (
  select distinct relation
  from   initial_data
),
initial_data_as_collection as (
  select relation, 
         cast(
           multiset (
             select val from initial_data where relation = d.relation
           ) 
           as sys.odcivarchar2list
         ) ss
  from   distinct_relations d
),
-- this is the recursive subquery
recursive_subq(relation, codes, values_listagg) as (
  select relation,
         relation codes,
         listagg(val,',') within group(order by val) values_listagg
  from   initial_data d
  group by relation
  union all
  select dr.relation,
         codes||','||dr.relation  codes,
         (
          select listagg(ind.val,',') within group (order by ind.val)
          from   initial_data ind
          where  ','||codes||','||dr.relation||',' like '%,'||ind.relation||',%'
         ) values_listagg
  from   recursive_subq rs,distinct_relations dr
  where  rs.relation < dr.relation
)
select codes
from   recursive_subq c,
       input_data_result r
where  c.values_listagg = r.input_values_listagg
```